# How to make table view via coding i know from IB?

Tags: iphone

I am new in iphone application and i want to make table view using coding so will you please give me some suggestion?

Comment: read the apple documentation!  download the apple iphone sample code! study them and if you dont understand or need clarification then ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [initWithFrame:style:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW13).

For example:

```
CGRect tableViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);
UITableView *myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableViewFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
// now add the new view to a window or another view
```